# how can i use $_COOKIE[] + PostID to execute the below code?

Tags: php, functions, cookies

someone can teach me how to combine `$_COOKIE[]` + PostID to count one visit by ip + post? I want use this to not use set_transient,

my actual code is this:

```
if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $key = $user_ip . 'x' . $postID;
    $value = array($user_ip, $postID);
    $visited = get_transient($key);
    if ( false === ( $visited ) ) {
        set_transient( $key, $value, 60*60*24 );
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '1');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
}
```

I want do the same but using cookie, is possible?

Comment: Note that you won't be able to cache these pages for logged in users